# How can I give an apache server access to a mounted folder?

Tags: apache, centos, webserver, wsgi, file-access

My apache server needs to serve files located in a mounted directory in the root folder. However, when the process attempts to access a file in that directory I get...

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denined 'path/to/file'
```

How can I give the apache server access to the files safely?

I am working on a CentOS machine.

Comment: Any luck in finding the answer?

Answer (score 0):

First unmount the shared directory.

chmod 775 <path>
chgrp apache <path>

Remount.

Would be one relatively safe way.

(assumes your apache user primary group is apache).